# How do I get the device given a UUID from libblkid?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, uuid

I know how to get the UUID of a device via libblkid... how do I do the reverse?

Given a UUID, I want to find what the device path is.

Comment: Get libblkid via a device?

Comment: The other way... Need the device given a UUID

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a programmatic way of doing this and this below worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <blkid/blkid.h>
char *get_disk(char *disk) {
   const char *uuid;
   char query[4096];

   snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "UUID=%s", disk);

   uuid = blkid_evaluate_tag(query, NULL, NULL);

   if (uuid == NULL) {
       uuid = "";
   }

   return strdup(uuid);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", get_disk(argv[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as `/dev/disk/by-uuid/{your-uuid}`. No C code or libaries  necessary.